# Find all the natural numbers where $ϕ(n)=110$ (Euler's totient function)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Find all the natural numbers where $ϕ(n)=110$ (Euler's totient function)

What the idea behind this kind of questions?

Comment: Do you mean Euler's Totient Function? Because if you do then its widespread notation is $\,\phi\,$ , *not* $\,\theta\,$ ...

Comment: Do you mean the [Euler Totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)? Euler has a lot of things named after him :)

Comment: Yes, I meant Euler's Totient Function, Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** Assuming you mean Euler's totient $\phi$, if you factor $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$, then

$$
\phi(n)=\phi(p_1^{e_1})\cdots\phi(p_k^{e_k})=p_1^{e_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_k^{e_k-1}(p_k-1)
$$

So look for primes $p$ such that $p-1\mid 110$ and go from that.

Comment: What did you mean by p−1∣110?

Comment: I mean that $p-1$ must divide $110$ if $p$ occurs in the prime factorisation of $n$.

Comment: So basically, If i decompose 110 and get 2⋅5⋅11. Say $p_1=2, p_2=5,p_3=11.$ And since ${p_1}^{e1}.{p_2}^{e2},{p_3}^{e3}$ and $e1=e2=e3=1$ then the numbers are 2,5,11?

Comment: I'm saying that it is possible that $2$ divides $n$, since $2-1=1$ divides $110$. However, if $7$ divides $n$, then since $7-1=6$ does **not** divide $110$, then $\phi(n)\ne 110$.

You should be able to run through the first few primes to see which can divide $n$, and which can't. Then, if this prime occurs twice in the factorisation, not only must $p-1$ divide 110, but $p$ itself must divide 110. You should be able to work out a small list of primes that can occur, bound the multiplicity with which they occur, and then from there write down an exhaustive list of all $n$ with $\phi(n)=110$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: if the prime decomposition of $\,n\,$ is

$$n=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{a_i}\implies \phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\implies$$

$$2\cdot5\cdot 11=110=\phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

The totient of a prime $p$ is $p-1$.  The totient of a prime power $p^n$ is $(p-1)p^{n-1}$.

There can't be more different odd divisors, then the power of $2$, because each new prime brings its own 'supply' of $2$, and an odd factor in a totient comes from odd primes.

So the solutions is a prime of the form $111$ or $11^2$.  The first is composite, the second is a power of a prime.  (In the case of $42$, which is $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$, both $43$ and $7^2$ work.)

Once one has addressed this issue, the next step is to consider the powers of $2$.  The euler totient of $2$ itself is 1, so if $n$ is odd, then both $n$ and $2n$ both have the same totient.  That applies here.